# Sequelize include is not working with associated table

Tags: node.js, model, include, sequelize.js, associations

I'm using sequelize 5.21.2

I have a users model:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const users = sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    firstname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },{
      timestamp: true,
      logging: console.log,
  });
  users.associate = function(models) {
    models.users.hasMany(models.messages);
  };
  return users;
};
```

A messages model:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const messages = sequelize.define('messages', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        message:{
            type: Sequelize.TEXT,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        timestamp: true,
        logging: console.log,
        scopes:{
            withUser:{
                include: [
                    {
                        model: sequelize.models.users
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });
    messages.associate = function(models) {
        models.messages.belongsTo(models.users);
    };
    return messages;
};
```

My controller:

```js
const db = require('../models');
const Messages = db.messages
exports.getOneMessage = (req, res) =>{
    Messages.scope(['withUser']).findByPk(req.query.id).then(message => {
        res.status(200).json({
            "description": "getOne - " + req.query.id,
            "message": message
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            "description": "Can not access",
            "error": err
        });
    });
};
```

I have this error:

```
Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.
```

- I've tried with hasOne in my users model instead of hasMany - No change
- I've tried with hasMany in my users model and removed the belongsTo of the messages model - No change
- I've tried with belongsTo in the messages model and removed the hasMany of the users model - No change
- I've dropped all tables and retried everything - No change

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem comes from the scope...
If I do my include in the controller itself everything is correct.
I'm using a lot of scopes in my project but the only one that causes me some trouble is the users model... I don't know why.

```js
const db = require('../models');
const Messages = db.messages
const Users = db.users
exports.getOneMessage = (req, res) =>{
    Messages.findByPk(req.query.id, {include:[Users]}).then(message => {
        res.status(200).json({
            "description": "getOne - " + req.query.id,
            "message": message
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            "description": "Can not access",
            "error": err
        });
    });
};
```